# What does this word 「どっ」 mean?

Tags: meaning, onomatopoeia

In the novel I'm currently reading I have seen it used a couple of times.

The context around it was:

1. How can a high school girl let out such strange shriek.
2. Or a girl shouldn't let out such a weird voice.

So I'm confused about what it means and why it is strange.

Instance 1:

> 放課後、隣を歩く凛香ちゃんがおもむろにそんなことを言うものだから、私は「どっ」と、女子高生にあるまじき声をあげてしまった。
> 遅れて 「カレシ」の3文字が耳の中に蘇って、顔が熱くなる。

Instance 2:

> 「写真、1枚ぐらいあるでしょ? 見せてよ」
> 「どっ」
> また変な声が出た。
> 私は女子高生、私は女子高生･･････
> 「そ、それはちょっと恥ずかしいんですけどー......」

Novel 塩対応の佐藤さんが俺にだけ甘い pages 137 and 139 respectively (from the beginning of chapter 3 after the first ♠️).

Comment: Please read [this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010) and provide more context *in original Japanese*.

Comment: What happened before the first passage?

Comment: It sounds strange coming from anyone, not only from a high school girl, though.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an independent word, but either a part of どうして/どういうこと ("Wha...!") or just a meaningless scream ("Argh!", "Oh").

(どっ is not a usual interjection used in a situation like this, but a fictional character can have an idiosyncratic way of being surprised...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be just onomatopoeia. If it means something, the closest I can think of is *WHAT?!*.